# Calling a function by its name (string) in React.Component using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm writing a React app with TypeScript. 
My component's state looks like this:

```js
type UploadState = {
  ...
  modal: string | null
  ...
}
```

In my `render` I have:

```js
render() {
  return <div>{this.renderModal()}</div>
}
```

somewhere in the code I have:

```js
this.setState({ modal: 'mappingModal' })
```

and finally `renderModel` is:

```js
renderModal = () => {
  if (this.state.modal === null) {
    return
  }
  return this[modal as keyof this]() //It doesn't work
}
```

I EXPECT to have the return value of `mappingModal`:

```js
mappingModal = () => {
  return <h1>Some text or whatever!</h1>
}
```

But I get this error because of `()` in `this[modal as keyof this]()` :

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
Type '{}' has no compatible call signatures.ts(2349)
```

And if I remove `()` I get this error in the browser:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child.
This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render.
Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
```

Any solution?

**UPDATE (POTENTIAL ANSWER)**

It seems if I use `this[modal as keyof Upload]()` - and `Upload` is my component name of course - I'll not have any problem. Hopefully it'll not cause any future bug

Comment: `this[modal as 'mappingModal']()` if `'mappingModal'` is a member of `this` should work. If you have a set of functions on `this` that have the same signature,  typing `modal` a union of those function names should work ..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Problem is that I don't know the value of `modal` in advance. So I can't say something like `this[modal as 'mappingModal']()`. Your solution works, but I'm looking for something more generic

Comment: I don't remember why `keyof this` is troublesome but the idea in whole doesn't look good. Why would a component allow to call any if its methods? It would allow `render` then, this would hang a browser. In case `modal` can depend on user input, this is security problem and design problem otherwise.

Comment: @estus `keyof this` is not fully known so it acts like a hidden type parameter to the class, derived classes could add to it so `this[keyof this]` does not get resolved inside the class since you don't really know what the type of `this` is. But I agree the design has a code smell about it ..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Notice that it's used inside an arrow, I would expect the compiler to be be pretty much sure what `this` is. Actually, this likely should be `keyof typeof this`. Doesn't work this way. Could be a limitation or a bug.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, @estus, It seems if I use `this[modal as keyof Upload]()` - and `Upload` is my component name of course - I'll not have any problem. Hopefully it'll not cause any future bug

Comment: @estus it knows it will be an instance of the class but it will not know all the members of `this` since the class could be derived and members added. This is one of the wierder behaviors around polymorphic `this`

Answer (score 1):

It seems if I use `this[modal as keyof Upload]()` - and `Upload` is my component name of course - I'll not have any problem. Like this:

```js
class Upload extends React.Component<UploadProps, UploadState> {
  ...
  renderModal = () => {
    if (this.state.modal === null) {
      return
    }
    return this[modal as keyof Upload]()
  }
  ...
}
```